# Why does removing an empty constraint cause a compiler error?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I observed some behavior I don't quite understand.  Here's a MWE

```hs
{-# Language PatternSynonyms, GADTs #-}
module Test where

data Succ a
data Zero

data Vec n a where
  EmptyVec :: Vec Zero a
  (:+) :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (Succ n) a

newtype Comp f g a = Comp (f (g a))

pattern CEv :: () => (n ~ Zero) => Comp (Vec n) g a
pattern CEv = Comp EmptyVec

t :: Comp (Vec m) (Vec n) r -> Bool
t (Comp (_ :+ _)) = True
t CEv = False
```

This compiles.  However we might notices that `CEv` has two constraints, `() =>` and `(n ~ Zero) =>`.  Since one of these is empty there can't be any harm in removing it right?  Well if we remove it `t` breaks.

```hs
pattern CEv :: (n ~ Zero) => Comp (Vec n) g a
pattern CEv = Comp EmptyVec
```

```
/XXXXXXX/src/Test.hs:18:3: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘m’ with ‘Zero’ arising from a pattern
      ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          t :: forall m n r. Comp (Vec m) (Vec n) r -> Bool
        at src/Test.hs:16:1-35
    • In the pattern: CEv
      In an equation for ‘t’: t CEv = False
    • Relevant bindings include
        t :: Comp (Vec m) (Vec n) r -> Bool (bound at src/Test.hs:17:1)
   |
18 | t CEv = False
   |   ^^^
```

I really don't know what's going on here.  Why does removing an empty constraint cause this to break?  What is the difference between the two types?

Comment: In a regular definition `foo :: c => d => T` is equivalent to `foo :: (c,d) => T`, and if `c` is empty it can be removed in both forms. However, in a pattern synonym the notation `pattern Foo :: c => d => T` has a different meaning, as explained in the answer by Li-yao Xia below. Perhaps reusing the same syntax with a different meaning was not so wise (*shrugs*).

Answer (score 4):

[Pattern synonyms](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/pattern_synonyms.html#typing-of-pattern-synonyms) have two sets of constraints: required and provided constraints.

```hs
pattern P :: Req => Prov => T
```

If there is only one constraint (i.e., one "`=>`" arrow), it is interpreted as a required constraint:

```hs
pattern P :: Req => T  -- means  Req => () => T, with an empty Prov = ()
```

So if you have an empty required constraint, there is no abbreviation for it:

```hs
pattern P :: () => Prov => T
```

Removing `()` there turns the `Prov` constraint into a required constraint, which has a different meaning (cf. the [GHC user guide section on Pattern synonyms](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/pattern_synonyms.html#typing-of-pattern-synonyms)).